# Javascript clear all cookies

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I am attempting to clear all of my cookies, some of which are set on a server and some of which are browser cookies.

I have tried using document.cookie = "" however this did not satisfy my needs so I wrote some Javascript code, which can be seen below

The pauseClearAllCookies function is called onload.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        //var cookie_names = new Array("__utma", "__utmb", "__utmc", "__utmz", "mortgage", "track_source","currency","selenium_testing","visit_secure_token", "rdb_history", "_csuid", "search", "finance", "searchhistory");

        function pauseClearAllCookies(){
            Set_Cookie("selenium_testing","1");
            drawTable();
            setTimeout("checkCookies();",1000);
            document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Gathering Cookies....";
        }

        var cookie_counter = 0;
        var cookieList;

        function checkCookies(){
            if(document.cookie.indexOf(";") != -1){
                cookieList = document.cookie.split(";");
            }else{
                cookieList = [document.cookie];
            }
            setTimeout("clearAllCookies();",1000);
        }

        function clearAllCookies(){

            document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Deleting Cookies....";

            if(cookie_counter < cookieList.length ){

                var cookieName = "";

                if(cookieList[cookie_counter].indexOf("=") != -1){
                    cookieName = cookieList[cookie_counter].split("=")[0];
                }else{
                    cookieName = cookieList[cookie_counter];
                }
                document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Deleting Cookie: "+cookieName;
                // clear js cookies
                Delete_Cookie(cookieName, '/', document.domain);
                Delete_Cookie(cookieName, '/', '.www.abc.co.uk');
                Delete_Cookie(cookieName, '/', 'www.abc.co.uk');
                Delete_Cookie(cookieName, '/', '.abc.co.uk');

                // clear server cookies
                Delete_Cookie(cookieName, '/', '');

                // increment counter
                cookie_counter++;

                drawTable();
                //recall the function
                setTimeout("clearAllCookies();",800);
            }else{
                Set_Cookie("selenium_testing","1");
            }
        }
        function drawTable() {
            var allcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
            document.getElementById('heading').innerHTML = allcookies.length + " cookie found";

            var table_html = "<table class='data'>";
            for(var i=0; i < allcookies.length; i++){
                var cookie = allcookies[i].split("=");
                table_html +=  "<tr>";
                table_html +=  "<td>"+(i+1)+"</td>";
                table_html +=  "<td>" + cookie[0] + "</td>";
                table_html +=  "<td>" + cookie[1] + "</td>";
                table_html +=  "<tr>";
            }

            table_html += "</table>";

            document.getElementById('table').innerHTML = table_html;
        }
    </script>
```

The problem is that every time I run this code one cookie is left behind, it is looped through however not deleted and its ALWAYS item number one in the Array. Any help in sorting this issues really would be very much appreciated.

Comment: BerggreenDK has a very good point. Beside, you don't even show your Delete_Cookie function...

Comment: where does cookie_counter get its value from? is this the complete code?

Answer (score 2):

have you tried to set all the cookie time formats to "a millisecond ago"? that ought to clear it up.

Comment: Did this fix your problem cameron? please mark the correct answer, if you found it so the community can grow which correct answers.

Answer (score 1):

Add https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie library and execute this script

for (var it in $.cookie()) $.removeCookie(it);

Comment: Keep in mind, this question is over 7 years old and the library you linked is no longer being maintained. Be mindful when answering old questions with new answers as the information relating to that specific question _may not be relevant_ due to the age

Answer (score 0):

The first object in an array is always labeled 0

.split()[0]